# Flutter Dart List - How to check if a list contains an object

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I wrote a function which returns true if an element is present in a list. I created an earlier version in which the list contained "ints" and it worked fine. Now I have a list of "complex" objects, and it seems it never detects if the object is present.
Here is the code :

```
bool addNewWordToBufferCarnetList(int? wordId) {
    CarnetWords newWord =
        CarnetWords(iD: wordId!, wrong: 0, right: 0, mastery: 0);
         if (_bufferCarnetList.contains(newWord) == true) {
          return false;
    } else {
      _bufferCarnetList.add(newWord);
      notifyListeners();
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Is there another way to see if the list contains the object ?

Comment: read carefully `List.contains` method documentation - it tells what you need to do to use it correctly

Comment: Hmm, I have read it several times... but I don't see what I am doing wrong. Is it because it is now a complex object ? Should I just use a for loop and do it "manually" ?

Comment: they say: *"The equality used to determine whether element is equal to an element of the iterable defaults to the Object.== of the element."* - so `==` operator is wrong in your class, if in doubts check how other classes implement it

Comment: I guess I don't understand their sentence... am unfortunately a beginner and not a native English speaker... So can the List.contains method be used in my case ?

Comment: if you have a list of `Rect` objects for example, you can use `List.contains` beacause `Rect` class implements `==` operator, like this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Rect/operator_equals.html - go to the bottom of this page and you will see the implementation, so what you need to do is to implement `==` operator in your `CarnetWords` class

Comment: So If I understand what you're saying, it means that when you create a new class of objects, the operator "==" doesn't exist "by default" ? For my CarnetWords : it means I couldn't check something like "If newWord == CarnetWords(102,2,3,2)" then....

Comment: it exists by default in [Object](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) class, but it is implemented as: *"The default behavior for all Objects is to return true if and only if this object and other are the same object."* - so if you want to use `contains` in your `CarnetWords` class you need to implement it in similar way `Rect` class is doing that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233049/discussion-between-sylvainjack-and-pskink).

Answer (score 2):

As suggested and explained by pskink, I had to override the == operator in my CarnetWords class for the "equality" to function.
Here is the code :

```
class CarnetWords {
 @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
    if (runtimeType != other.runtimeType) return false;
    return other is CarnetWords && other.iD == iD;
  }
 @override
  int get hashCode => iD.hashCode;

  int? iD;
  int? wrong;
  int? right;
  double? mastery;
  CarnetWords(
      {@required this.iD,
      @required this.wrong,
      @required this.right,
      @required this.mastery});
}
```

Thanks pskink for your help and patience !

Comment: Hello again :) Are you online ?

Comment: I had a crazy pb with Textfield. I don't know if you can see my post from here. I managed to find a way around it, but I still don't understand why it didn't work...

Comment: i dont see any `Textfield` in the code you posted

Comment: In this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769519/cant-seem-to-save-the-value-of-a-textfield-for-future-use/67769625#67769625